# Why do Indians or Hindus celebrate Dev Deepavali?

Tags: puranas, festivals, ganga

After Deepavali, Hindus or Indians celebrate [Dev Deepavali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev_Deepawali_(Varanasi)).

What is the reason for celebrating Dev Deepavali?

Does this festival or tradition find mention in the Puranas?

Comment: Wiki says it is same as Kartika Poornima, which is believed to happen after Tripura Dahana.

Comment: Accepting the answer just after 15 minutes is too early.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes, you're right. "Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well." from [help centre](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev Diwali is celebrated (in Varanasi) on the day of Kartika Poornima (कार्तिक पूर्णिमा) which is also known as Tripura Purnima (त्रिपुर पूर्णिमा) according to Hindu Panchang.

The mythological story (पौराणिक कथा) related to this is about slaughter of demon/devil "Tripura" (त्रिपुर) by lord Shiva with the help of Vishnu & Brahma. And Devas celebrated this day like Diwali.

You can find Scriptural Reference for this story in Srimad Bhagavat MahaPurana (7.10.52 to 7.10.71).

You can read full story at [Srimadbhagavatam.in](http://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/canto7/chapter10.html) & [Vedabase.com](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/10)

> ......
>   SB 7.10.56 — Thereafter, when the demons had begun to destroy the higher planetary systems, the rulers of those planets went to Lord Śiva, fully surrendered unto him and said: **Dear Lord, we demigods living in the three worlds are about to be vanquished. We are your followers. Kindly save us.**
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   SB 7.10.67 — **My dear King Yudhiṣṭhira, the most powerful Lord Śiva joined the arrows to his bow, and at noon he set fire to all three residences of the demons and thus destroyed them.**
>   SB 7.10.68 — Seated in their airplanes in the sky, the inhabitants of the higher planetary systems beat many kettledrums. **The demigods, saints, Pitās, Siddhas and various great personalities showered flowers on the head of Lord Śiva, wishing him all victory, and the Apsarās began to chant and dance with great pleasure.**
>   SB 7.10.69 — O King Yudhiṣṭhira, thus Lord Śiva is known as **Tripurāri**, the annihilator of the three dwellings of the demons, because he burnt these dwellings to ashes. Being worshiped by the demigods, headed by Lord Brahmā, Lord Śiva returned to his own abode.

*This may be the belief/mythology related to the celebration of Deva Diwali.*

For further information on celebration, tradition and rituals, you may visit: [Bharat Discovery](http://bharatdiscovery.org/india/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%95_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE), [Varanasi.org.in](http://www.varanasi.org.in/dev-diwali), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev_Deepawali_(Varanasi))

Comment: But where exactly it says Shiva did Tripura Dahana on Kartika Pournami?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I've (only) tried to relate the possible mythology behind celebration of Deva Diwali. And yes, this scriptural reference doesn't provide any traditional or ritjals.

Comment: Ok. But i think it is fine if scriptures explicitly say that.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I agree if anyone can answer with scripture explicitly say about Deva Diwali tradition & rituals, then s/he recommended to add answer. (But I didn't find such)

Comment: There is no mention of Pournami in your answer.! Where is it mentioned that Shiva did tripura dahana on Kartika Pournami?

Comment: @SreeCharan I agree as said before. And btw, I've not asked OP to accept my answer :P /cc TheDestroyer

Comment: @Pandya Actually, i searched a lot for that reference. I want the same reference to answer this question [What is Kaarthika masam? who should follow it?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9656/3500). Lord Shiva is worshipped more in some areas during Kartika Masam, though Lord Vishnu is also worshipped. Kartika Masam is related to Tripura Dahana.

Comment: @SreeCharan btw, your close vote looks disfavour your [comment](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16884/why-do-indians-or-hindus-celebrate-dev-deepavali/16892#comment43333_16892) Haha