# Why "Margasheersha" month is auspicious?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

In "Bhagavad Gita", Bhagwan says "I am Margashirsha amongst the months". But majority of the Hindu festivals and Muhurtas fall not in "Margashirsha" month.
In fact, as [this Q](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9656/what-is-kaarthika-masam-who-should-follow-it)
discusses, "Kartik" month is very auspicious.
Then why Bhagwan says so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some commentators who have elaborated that line say it is because grains are harvested in that month and  materially people become happy.

See [here](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-35/)

This line seems talking neither in spiritual terms nor in terms of auspiciousness for marriages etc. This seems appropriate understanding since immediately Krishna says something on similar lines 'I am Spring amongst seasons'

Some commentaries give further insights into that line. See [here](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?hcrskd=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=35)

It suggests two reasons.

> मासानां मार्गशीर्षोऽहम् -- जिस अन्नसे सम्पूर्ण प्रजा जीवित रहती है? उस
>   (वर्षासे होनेवाले) अन्नकी उत्पत्ति मार्गशीर्ष महीनेमें होती है। इस
>   महीनेमें नये अन्नसे यज्ञ भी किया जाता है। महाभारतकालमें नया वर्ष
>   मार्गशीर्षसे ही आरम्भ होता था। इन विशेषताओंके कारण भगवान्ने
>   मार्गशीर्षको अपनी विभूति बताया है

In this Month, 
1.new grains are harvested by which all living beings sustain. Also, the grains would be used in yajnas performed. 
2. During the times of Mahabharat, new year  starts with margasirsha month . That's why Krishna counted this month among his opulences.

Comment: Although I fully respect the commentator in the above link, I am not convinced by the logic in that link. Because, everywhere else in "Geeta", the Bhagwan is talking spiritual and/or "nishkaam karma". Then how come is he saying about just "good harest" logic ?? Doesn't fit in. Any other references from other distinguished commentators?

Comment: @Vineet I updated answer. Next line also has nothing spiritual. I am Spring amongst seasons. That link has multiple commentaries. Sridhara Swami also says so. I have one more English commentary book of Baladeva Vidysbhusana which is not online he says similar thing.

Comment: can you pl post url or scanned image for "Baladeva Vidysbhusana's" commentary if possible? Thanks.

Comment: In "Geeta Rahasya", Lokamanya Tilak mentions that "earlier Margashirsha used to be the first month" and reference given is "Mahabharat - Anushasana Parva 106, 109; Valmiki Ramayana - 3.16; Bagwat Mahapuran - 11.16.27. Further he says that this is explained in his book "Orion". IMHO this logic makes sense than "harvest logic".

Comment: If someone can translate into English this portion from https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=35&scsh=1&scang=1&scram=1&scanand=1&scjaya=1&scmad=1&scval=1&scms=1&scsri=1&scvv=1&scpur=1&scneel=1&scdhan=1 we will get other views on the same. I could see some commentaries talk on harvesting grain lines and thus animals and humans becoming happy. Vallabhacharya says कुमारिकाकामपूरणकालत्वात् भोगयोग्यत्वाच्च मे विभूतिः it seems like certain desire gets fulfilled. But if some one can translate these lines, that would be better. I made guess

Comment: @Vineet https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?hcrskd=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=35. This commentary suggests both reasons. मासानां मार्गशीर्षोऽहम् -- जिस अन्नसे सम्पूर्ण प्रजा जीवित रहती है? उस (वर्षासे होनेवाले) अन्नकी उत्पत्ति मार्गशीर्ष महीनेमें होती है। इस महीनेमें नये अन्नसे यज्ञ भी किया जाता है। महाभारतकालमें नया वर्ष मार्गशीर्षसे ही आरम्भ होता था। इन विशेषताओंके कारण भगवान्ने मार्गशीर्षको अपनी विभूति बताया है

Comment: pl. edit your answer with above comment. IMO that would be the right answer. I have up voted the comment.

Comment: @Vineet edited the answer